# how to call rest using SSL from extjs

Tags: javascript, wcf, iis, extjs

My configuration is this:

- REST server: WCF-REST hosted on a windows service.
- Web server: IIS for hosting my html+js files (Sencha ExtJS).
- Client: The client is written using Sencha ExtJS

I have two authentication/security configurations on the REST server:
 1. http with no authentication at all.
 2. https (ssl) with basic authentication.

The client works great on the no authentication/no ssl option.
But, I can't make it work using the https/authentication.

If I'm trying to use the browser to access the https url, I get a message that the server certificate is not valid. I can ignore it, and a popup for user/password appear. After entering the user/password, I get the REST response.

What am I missing to make it work using the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your development server is using a self-signed certificate; if that's the case, you're asking an untrusted transaction to proceed without the user's consent, and I'm pretty sure there's no way to do that in Javascript.

HTTPS transactions need to establish trust in order to keep your data secure. Usually this is accomplished with a certificate that's been shared with and validated by a third-party, but as developers we often use self-signed certificates during development and testing because they're quick, simple, and free. Those self-signed certs need to be known at each end of the transaction to replace the trust that would've been established with a third-party cert.

If your browser doesn't have a copy of your self-signed cert installed, you'll see the typical "oh-no-you're-visiting-the-most-dangerous-website-ever" message that you mention. The browser gives the user a UI to temporarily accept that certificate (establishing the needed trust), allowing the transaction to proceed. Ajax transactions have no such luxury - the browser simply lets the transaction die because there is no user interface. I think we should all be a little thankful that there's no way to defeat that in Javascript.

Your choices are:

1. Temporarily accepting a transaction in one tab or window may establish trust for transactions in other tabs/windows on some browsers (I use this approach with Chrome).
2. Install the certificate in your browser (the 'how' depends greatly on your browser of choice)
3. Get that certificate signed a little sooner than you'd planned - you'll need it anyway because you're working on the next Facebook, right? :-)